# How do I make a wooden garter/captive washer?

Tags: tool-maintenance, jig, design

I wish to build a tail vise using the Shop Fox D3258 Bench Screw ([Link to Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00012XCCA)).

This bench screw comes with the screw itself and the cast-iron mount for moving the block in the table, however it does not come with a way to secure the handle to your bench, presumably because there are so many potential ways of executing the mounting.

Someone mentioned in a forum elsewhere that one could fashion a wooden washer to hold the piece in place, but I'm not sure how one would execute that.

My question is: given an inner diameter of approximately 1", with a slot approximately 1/4", what is the best way to produce a washer or garter out of hardwood that could hold the bench screw from unscrewing out of the vise?  Should I get 1/4" stock, jigsaw two crescents and then screw them together over the slot in the bench screw?

Comment: I think The nut is meant to mount and the tip is mean to apply the force (given the rounded tip).

Answer (score 2):

Well One thing I can envision is to take a piece of lumber (3/4"-1"? ) and if you have a way to tap it to have the same threads as your clamp  have it turned on up to the handle, when you tighten it down to lock it from the front.

[image: The nut]

Comment: Search for 'wood threading kit' on google - they make kits to make both the male and female threads for stuff like this (often acme threads or similar) which I tend to prefer. Good luck, and may your blades stay ever sharp!